# What is the difference between element.offsetLeft and jQuery's element.offset()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

What is the main difference between those two?  It seems like sometimes the browser accepts jQuery's element.offset() and not typical element.offsetLeft

Very nice example of this is in this code

```
  (function () {

    var mX, mY, distance,
    $distance = $('#distance span'),
        $element = $('#element');

    function calculateDistance(elem, mouseX, mouseY) {
        return Math.floor(Math.sqrt(Math.pow(mouseX - (elem.offset().left + (elem.width() / 2)), 2) + Math.pow(mouseY - (elem.offset().top + (elem.height() / 2)), 2)));
    }

    $(document).mousemove(function (e) {
        mX = e.pageX;
        mY = e.pageY;
        alert(mX);
        alert((mX - ($element.offsetLeft + ($element.width() / 2))));
        distance = calculateDistance($element, mX, mY);
        $distance.text(distance);
    });

})();
```

If you replace elem.offset().left with elem.offsetLeft or $element.offsetLeft it returns NaN , altought if you just alert offset().left //returns 182.5 or alert offsetLeft //returns 183 whats the magic behind it?

demo from css-tricks http://jsfiddle.net/chriscoyier/t5Kts/

Comment: jQuery objects don't have `offsetLeft` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery offset() gives the position of the element relative to the document root.  element.offsetLeft gives the left position relative to its parent element.

To use element.offsetLeft with jQuery you'd need to to access the actual DOM element, not the jQuery object representation of the element:

```
$element[0].offsetLeft
```

Comment: it still says "NaN" after that

Comment: I updated your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/t5Kts/922/.  The `calculateDistance` function no longer uses jQuery functions but all native javascript (`offsetLeft`, `offsetTop`, `offsetWidth`, `offsetHeight`).  When calling it, you pass in the DOM element, not the jQuery object: `distance = calculateDistance($element[0], mX, mY);`